# How to set up clang-format (automatically format code when coding without doing anything)?

Tags: emacs, clang-format

I am trying to install the clang-format automatic format tool, I have installed clang-format with `M-x package-install clang-format`
and I can see it in `M-x list-packages`.

My ~/.emacs is:

```
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  (when no-ssl
    (warn "\
Your version of Emacs does not support SSL connections,
which is unsafe because it allows man-in-the-middle attacks.
There are two things you can do about this warning:
1. Install an Emacs version that does support SSL and be safe.
2. Remove this warning from your init file so you won't see it again."))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)

;; clang-format
(require 'clang-format)
(global-set-key [C-M-tab] 'clang-format-region)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
           (function (lambda ()
                    (add-hook 'write-contents-functions
                              (lambda() (progn (clang-format-buffer) nil))))))

 (add-hook 'cpp-mode-common-hook
          (function (lambda ()
                      (add-hook 'write-contents-functions
                                (lambda() (progn (clang-format-buffer) nil))))))


;; irony-mode
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
(add-hook 'objc-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
(add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)

;; company mode
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'company-mode)

;; flycheck-mode
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(eval-after-load 'flycheck
'(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'flycheck-irony-setup))

;; eldoc-mode
(add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-eldoc)

(global-linum-mode)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (list-packages-ext clang-format flycheck-clang-tidy flycheck-clang-analyzer elpy irony-eldoc company-irony flycheck-irony flycheck irony))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.

 '(linum ((t (:inherit (shadow default) :foreground "yellow")))))
```

But clang-format does not appear at the bottom of emacs window while Irony, FlyC, ElDoc and Abbrev appear.

Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [clang-format github](https://github.com/sonatard/clang-format) instructions:

```
(require 'clang-format)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c i") 'clang-format-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c u") 'clang-format-buffer)

(setq clang-format-style-option "llvm")
```

It won't appear in the status line as it's not a minor mode.
You have to set key bindings to the function you want to use, like in the given example.